# API Traffic Shaping/Throttling Strategies For Tenant Isolation

Tags: api, throttling, rate-limiting, trafficshaping

I'll start my question by providing some context about what we're doing and the problems we're facing.

- We are currently building a SaaS (hosted on Amazon AWS) that consists of several microservices that sit behind an API gateway (we're using Kong).
- The gateway handles authentication (through consumers with API keys) and exposes the APIs of these microservices that I mentioned, all of which are stateless (there are no sessions, cookies or similar).
- Each service is deployed using ECS services (one or more docker containers per service running on one or more EC2 machines) and load balanced using the Amazon Application Load Balancer (ALB).
- All tenants (clients) share the same environment, that is, the very same machines and resources. Given our business model, we expect to have few but "big" tenants (at first).
- Most of the requests to these services translate in heavy resource usage (CPU mainly) for the duration of the request. The time needed to serve one request is in the range of 2-10 seconds (and not ms like traditional "web-like" applications). This means we serve relatively few requests per minute where each one of them take a while to process (background or batch processing is not an option).

Right now, we don't have a strategy to limit or throttle the amount of requests that a tenant can make on a given period of time. Taken into account the last two considerations from above, it's easy to see this is a problem, since it's almost trivial for a tenant to make more requests than we can handle, causing a degradation on the quality of service (even for other tenants because of the shared resources approach).

We're thinking of strategies to limit/throttle or in general prepare the system to "isolate" tenants, so one tenant can not degrade the performance for others by making more requests than we can handle:

- **Rate limiting**: Define a maximum requests/m that a tenant can make. If more requests arrive, drop them. Kong even has a plugin for it. Sadly, we use a "pay-per-request" pricing model and business do not allow us to use this strategy because we want to serve as many requests as possible in order to get paid for them. If excess requests take more time for a tenant that's fine.
- **Tenant isolation**: Create an isolated environment for each tenant. This one has been discarded too, as it makes maintenance harder and leads to lower resource usage and higher costs.
- **Auto-scaling**: Bring up more machines to absorb bursts. In our experience, Amazon ECS is not very fast at doing this and by the time these new machines are ready it's possibly too late.
- **Request "throttling"**: Using algorithms like Leaky Bucket or Token Bucket at the API gateway level to ensure that requests hit the services at a rate we know we can handle.

Right now, we're inclined to take option 4. We want to implement the request throttling (traffic shaping) in such a way that all requests made within a previously agreed rate with the tenant (enforced by contract) would be passed along to the services without delay. Since we know in advance how many requests per minute each tenant is gonna be making (estimated at least) we can size our infrastructure accordingly (plus a safety margin).

If a burst arrives, the excess requests would be queued (up to a limit) and then released at a fixed rate (using the leaky bucket or similar algorithm). This would ensure that a tenant can not impact the performance of other tenants, since requests will hit the services at a predefined rate. Ideally, the allowed request rate would be "dynamic" in such a way that a tenant can use some of the "requests per minute" of other tenants that are not using them (within safety limits). I believe this is called the "Dynamic Rate Leaky Bucket" algorithm. The goal is to maximize resource usage.

My questions are:

- **Is the proposed strategy a viable one?** Do you know of any other viable strategies for this use case?
- **Is there an open-source, commercial or SaaS service that can provide this traffic shaping capabilities?** As far as I know Kong or Tyk do not support anything like this, so... Is there any other API gateway that does?
- **In case Kong does not support this, How hard it is to implement something like what I've described as a plugin?** We have to take into account that it would need some shared state (using Redis for example) as we're using multiple Kong instances (for load balancing and high availability).

Thank you very much,
Mikel.

Answer (score 2):

Managing request queue on Gateway side is indeed tricky thing, and probably the main reason why it is not implemented in this Gateways, is that it is really hard to do right. You need to handle all the distributed system cases, and in addition, it hard makes it "safe", because "slow" clients quickly consume machine resources.

Such pattern usually offloaded to client libraries, so when client hits rate limit status code, it uses smth like exponential backoff technique to retry requests. It is way easier to scale and implement.

Can't say for Kong, but Tyk, in this case, provides two basic numbers you can control, quota - maximum number of requests client can make in given period of time, and rate limits - safety protection. You can set rate limit 1) per "policy", e.g for group of consumers (for example if you have multiple tiers of your service, with different allowed usage/rate limits), 2) per individual key 3) Globally for API (works together with key rate limits). So for example, you can set some moderate client rate limits, and cap total limit with global API setting.

If you want fully dynamic scheme, and re-calculate limits based on cluster load, it should be possible. You will need to write and run this scheduler somewhere, from time to time it will perform re-calculation, based on current total usage (which Tyk calculate for you, and you get it from Redis) and will talk with Tyk API, by iterating through all keys (or policies) and dynamically updating their rate limits.

Hope it make sense :)